# ExtJS Can I use an IF statement inside the same component

Tags: javascript, extjs, frontend

I'm managing a software with a framework `ExtJS 3.3.1`.
My problem is that I want to use a component depending by the caller.
I have a `region` of a `tabpanel` and I want to use this pseudo-code:

```
items: [{
    region: 'center',
    title: 'List of Transmissions',

    // PSEUDO CODE START
    IF (RECEIVE A CALLER BY THIS COMPONENT) {
        id: 'idTab1'
        xtype: 'typeA'
    }
    ELSE IF(RECEIVE A CALLER BY THIS COMPONENT) {
        id: 'idTab2'
        xtype: 'typeB'
    }
    // PSEUDO CODE END
}]
```

Could someone help me to translate it in `ExtJS 3.3.1` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can used binding function for hide/show typeA and typeB with a caller variable.

You can used afterrender or boxready listener for create you'r cmp after the load of the parent panel.

I can't create fiddle cause i don't have forum sencha account yet but you can tried with this code on this https://fiddle.sencha.com/ :

```
var callerVar = false;

new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'firstPanel',
            hidden: callerVar
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: 'scndPanel',
            hidden: !callerVar
        }
    ]
});
```

You to decide how to update callerVar, i don't how you want to do this.

Comment: Itsn't more clear, could you do a Fiddle with ExtJS 3.4 ?

Comment: I did my best but I use ExtJS 6 so it's hard to adapt to version 3 ;) I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Enzo BLACHON and his idea.
I'm trying to solve using the `layout:'card'` and add/remove the ID. According to me even if it solve my problem, it's too compicated, I would like to ask if there is a manner less complicated and more useful to improve the quality of the code:

```
id: 'flip_ID',
region: 'center',
layout: 'card',
activeItem: 0,
items: [
   {
     itemId: 'idTab1',
     xtype: 'typeA'
   },
   {
     itemId: 'idTab2',
     xtype: 'typeB'
   }]
```

When there is a call to the first component I added this code:

```
var center = Ext.getCmp('flip_ID');
center.add(Ext.ComponentMgr.create({
       itemId: 'idTab1',
       xtype: 'typeA'
}));
center.getLayout().setActiveItem('idTab1');
center.remove('idTab2', true);
```

When there is a call to the second component I added this code:

```
 var center = Ext.getCmp('flip_ID');
    center.add(Ext.ComponentMgr.create({
           itemId: 'idTab2',
           xtype: 'typeB'
    }));
    center.getLayout().setActiveItem('idTab2');
    center.remove('idTab1', true);
```